# Moodle Inconsistencies, Flowplayer, or Server?

Tags: server, video, moodle

We are trying to decide if an issue we're having with Moodle and our videos is a flowplayer issue, a video issue, or a network issue. Any input is welcome.

We've had videos in our Moodle (version 1.9, we're working on an upgrade on a different server) up for weeks, or even months. After that time, some of them have suddenly just stopped working.

When they don't work, they just don't load. The videos work when we first upload them. With flowplayer, we don't get errors, just a blank screen.

We have re-uploaded our videos several times when this has happened, but we really would like to know what's causing it so that we can prevent it.

There are also no keyframe issues with the video.

Re-uploading the video is not fixing the issue, but the video plays fine on local machines.

It's happened twice with two different videos both in the 1 - 2 hour time range.

Deleting and re-uploading or just replacing footage is not working to fix the issue online.

The videos are available for about a month and then go bad...

We are using Flowplayer 3.2.4

**Here are the Flowplayer snippets (I've replaced the actual site name with SITENAME):**

*Page:*

```
<div style="margin-left:100px; margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:15px;">
<h2 style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:16px;">Online Mastery Day 3    Part 3</h2>
<br />
<iframe   src="http://<SITENAME>/etradercompanion/theme/aardvark_pro_mastery/online-  mastery-d3-03.php" width="540" height="405" scrolling="no" border="0"></iframe>
<br />
</div>
```

*Video:*

```
<a class="player" id="fms" style="display:block;width:540px;height:405px;"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://<SITENAME>/general/js/flowplayer-    3.2.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$f("fms", "/assets/flash/flowplayer.commercial-3.2.5.swf", {
key: '#$34fc5b345bb29400658',
clip: {
url: 'mastery/2013-09-19-Mastery-Class-Online-03',
provider: 'influxis',
autoPlay: false
},
plugins: {
influxis: { url: '/assets/flash/flowplayer.rtmp-3.2.3.swf',
netConnectionUrl: 'rtmp://67.225.227.77/vod/' }
}
});
</script>
```

We are currently trying to find answers through various searches, but have not had any luck. I will continue to post more info as I come across it...but if there's anyone who knows or has ideas, it's welcome.